# Capybara find all links on page and check url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webdriver, capybara

I want to check that all links on a page contain a certain element. This is the current web_step I have but it is not working. Any ideas?

```
Then /^all links above footer should countain "([^"]+)"$/ do |parameter|
  al = page.all('a')
  al.each do |i|
    i.include?(parameter).should be_true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to assert against a particular attribute of each `a` element - if you're checking that the 'src' attribute contains 'parameter' then:

```
i[:href].include?(parameter).should be_true
```

Or, to make better use of the rspec matchers (and get better failure messages):

```
i[:href].should include parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

`[:src]` no longer appears to work. Use `[:href]` instead.

Comment: I recommend either making this a comment to Jon M's answer or fleshing it out so that it can stand on its own without reading Jon M's answer.